# Ruby interface for abstracting legacy database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, dynamic

I'm building an application on top of a legacy SQL Enterprise database with existing schema but I also want to support PostgreSQL with a similar but more conventional ActiveRecord schema.  I've got a set of ActiveRecord classes for each database that abstract the schema differences and present a common interface for views and controllers.  I'd like to be able to switch the set of classes used at an application level according to environment/config.

In any other language I'd have an object factory that spawn objects using the appropriate classes for the environment.  But I understand that such patterns are overkill for ruby.

If I have two classes, IssuePg and IssueLegacy, is there a way that I can configure my app so a call to Issue.new instantiates the appropriate model?  I know I can assign the class to a variable but where would I do it so it would be system wide and invisible to Rails and compatible with scaffolding, so I could scaffold around Issue and later change Issue superclass according to environment?

I also need a separate set of migrations for each environment - any thoughts? Or is this a source control problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One heavyhanded way you could do this is to use an environment or command line variable, and then do something like:

```
if Rails.env['db_support'] == :legacy
    require '/path/to/legacy/ar/objects'
else
    require '/path/to/normal/ar/objects'
end
```

This segregates your models and keeps the codebase a bit cleaner.

Comment: I suppose it could be that simple.  I've been getting lost in all the possible options ruby presents.